# from csv to json, unknown symbols nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv

Really I don't know what to do. Please help to solve this problem. I have a CSV file, I transfer it to an array:

```
import csvToJson from 'convert-csv-to-json';
import fs from 'fs';

const URL_01 = `${__dirname}/URL/price.csv`;

//Unnecessary code removed for clarity...

app.get('/all', (req, res) => {
    let json = csvToJson.getJsonFromCsv(URL_01);
    res.send(json);
});
```

I got this:
[image]

How to get the correct data in UTF-8??

Comment: Try to edit [this](https://github.com/iuccio/csvToJson/blob/master/src/util/fileUtils.js#L8) line and provide 'utf-8' as the encoding option: `return fs.readFileSync(fileInputName, 'UTF-8').toString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tactic should be:

```
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
var csv = require('csv');

var converterStream = iconv.decodeStream('win1251');

fs.createReadStream('file-in-win1251.txt')
  .pipe(iconv.decodeStream('win1251'))
  .pipe(csv.parse())
  .pipe(csv.stringify())
  .pipe(process.stdout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **csvtojson** library instead of convert-csv-to-json.

You will see examples here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the output from csvToJson in JSON.parse(JSON.stringify());

```
app.get('/all', (req, res) => {
     let json = csvToJson.getJsonFromCsv(URL_01);
     res.send(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json)));
});
```

`JSON.Stringify()` may parse the data causing the errors. But of course, you'll want to convert it back to JSON from the String using `JSON.parse()`. Although, it's difficult to say without knowing the problem characters.

Comment: the problem characters are the full language(alphabet).